# How to root Samsung Galaxy S10/S10e/S10+

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Samsung Galaxy S10 unfortunately [comes up](https://piunikaweb.com/2019/03/25/samsung-galaxy-s10-remove-bundled-bloatwares-without-root/) with apps that I don't need:

> Unfortunately [...] the South Korean smartphone maker decided to bundle tons of apps inside the firmware of their flagship phone.
>
> Majority of the bundled apps inside S10 are part of the Samsung ecosystem, although third party apps like Facebook can also be found there. Some of them can be disabled from the Settings, but not all.

I also want to use a few root-only apps, and need write access to `/data/data/` for backup/restore purposes.

**Question**: How can I root my Samsung Galaxy S10e as easily and risk-free as possible?
*(I generalized the question to all S10 variants, but please let me know if methods differ enough that separate question are required)*

Comment: there is nemesis kernel meanwhile, no need for pressing buttons on boot

Comment: I had never heard of this, but it sounds interesting! Feel free to propose an answer :-) Unlike Magisk it does not look open source though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to root my Samsung S10e using topjohnwu's Magisk-based work. Here is the procedure, it also works for S10 and S10+:

https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root

The procedure is rather complex, but fortunately a YouTuber has made an easy-to-follow video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3a8YnWT3yk

The video is directly based on John's instructions, so I recommend reading/watching both before each operation to make sure you understand correctly before executing.

The only drawback of this method is that when you want to reboot your device, you will always need to press simultaneously Bitxby+Power+Volume Up until the logo appears. If you boot normally, it will start normally but you won't have root.

Dedicated xda thread (including donation links for John): https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s10/development/magisk-root-galaxy-s10-series-t3918699

[image]

Comment: Perhaps unrelated (and a subject for an full blown SO question) but how do you in fact OEM Unlock a device when this option is not available at all in dev options? I've seen too many to count "guides" out there and NONE address this issue. Are you aware of a tool/software/terminal incantation that will enable OEM unlocking a device that won't show it in the UI (and actually works?) Many thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderF: Is your question for a Samsung Galaxy S10/S10e/S10+ device?

Comment: Indeed @Nicolas. Mine is S10e.

Comment: @AlexanderF: Interesting! For me `OEM unlocking` is between `Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log` and `Running services`. Could you please create a new question, including a screenshot of developer options? Thanks!