# Multiple User Accounts on Galaxy S10/S10+/S10e

Tags: multi-user, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Samsung has disabled the [Multiple User Accounts](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865483) feature on the Galaxy S10.

How to set up multiple accounts? I mean the ability to create a separate Android home with their own app settings.

I want to be able to lend the phone to a kid or friend for a day without worrying about them messing with my files or banking accounts.

Comment: The clean way would be to install a custom ROM that supports multiple user accounts. Activating this feature using root may be possible however you don't know exactly what Samsung has removed and what not. Especially missing GUI elements regarding multiple user accounts can't just be enabled if they had been removed from the ROM.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on S10e using [this guide](https://beebom.com/how-enable-multiple-user-accounts-any-android/).

1. [Root your S10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212265/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s10-s10e-s10). That step is required for that procedure.
2. Install [BuildProp Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor) (or equivalent) and run it, grant it root permission

   [image]
3. Touch the pen icon at the top
4. Scroll to the very bottom of the text file, and add the following two lines:

   ```
   fw.max_users=3
   fw.show_multiuserui=1
   ```

   [image]
5. Touch "Save and exit"
6. Check that the lines are correct. No extra spaces, all characters written exactly as below:

   [image]
7. Reboot
8. In Settings, search for "Users". You can now add new users:

   [image]

The user addition UI is a bit buggy, screens randomly go forward/back. But just be patient, sometimes try a step again, and you should be able to get the new user created.

*Note: People who really don't want to root their device for some reason can try this procedure to edit `build.prop`: https://beebom.com/how-edit-build-prop-without-root/*

Comment: Do you know of an easy way to switch users?  Currently I need to go to the settings->accounts->users->user->switch which is lots of steps to just switch.  The icon isn't in the pulldown