# Mulitple user accounts on Samsung A20e

Tags: samsung, multi-user

I have a Samsung Galaxy A20e, apparently Android lets you have multiple user accounts... but I dont see this listed anywhere in the settings for my phone?

Comment: That Android allows multiple user accounts does not necessarily means a Samsung phone running Android also provides this feature. Each phone manufacturer can modify their used Android version to a certain degree.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Multiple User Accounts on Galaxy S10/S10+/S10e](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213231/44325) (although for different models, possibly the same reason and solution)