# Remove notifications "Activate Anti-malware service" and "Battery fully charged" on rooted Samsung S10

Tags: root-access, notifications, malware, samsung-galaxy-s-10

On my Samsung S10e device I often get these notifications:

> Device care - Activate Anti-malware service

and

> Battery fully charged

When I try to turn one of them off, I am told:

> These notifications can't be turned off

Which raises the question: On my [rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215605/501) device, *how* can I turn them off?

Solutions that only work for one of these notifications are OK.

Comment: This is not an answer, but hopefully providing a background/context to [why it cannot be turned off easily](https://www.androidpit.com/samsung-galaxy-s10-pre-installed-anti-malware): "*McAfee [...] is an integral part of the so-called "device maintenance" in Samsung's One UI user interface; formerly Samsung Experience and TouchWiz.*"

Comment: Have you tried Magisk modules? [Debloater](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-terminal-debloater-debloat-t3584163/page97) to debloat that McAfee thing which is I believe under the *Device care* or debloat Device Care itself? If that's not working out, the [hidden settings](https://github.com/skittles9823/hidden-settings) Magisk module. Yet another option - if you can get to install Gravitybox on your device, see under Advanced tuning (Framework and System UI) Options if you can disable.//

Comment: //These may turn out to be *not helpful* but that's the best I can think of, since I don't own the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "flex your root muscle" so to speak, there are options using Xposed modules, but these options do not require it.

Battery full notifications are a bit of a workaround:

- Open Settings and select the Notifications option
- Click See All under the Recently Sent list
- Select All from the dropdown in the top left
- Click the 3 dots in the top right and click Show system apps
- Select System UI
- Click the Battery full item
- Edit the options as desired

As for Device care, that is a little less of a workaround:

- Open Settings and select the Device care option
- Click the 3 dots in the upper right of this screen
- Select Advanced
- Slide the Notifications switch to off

This option may have been part of the Android 10 update. If you do not have this option:

- Open Settings and select the Notifications option
- Click See All under the Recently Sent list
- Select All from the dropdown in the top left
- Click the 3 dots in the top right and click Show system apps
- Select Settings
- Click the Device care (Important) item
- Edit the options as desired
- Return to the previous list
- Click the Device care item
- Edit the options as desired

Keep in mind that this will disable **all** Device care notifications. If you went with the second method, you may want to try disabling one at a time to remove the notification you want without necessarily removing all of them.

Comment: Thanks! `Battery full` was in `Silent` so I switched it to `Silent and minimized`. When clicking the 3 dots in `Settings`>`Device care` I only see: Auto optimization, AUto restart, App issue history, SHow icon on Apps screen, About Device care... I don't see Advanced.

Comment: I can confirm that the battery icon does not appear anymore when reaching 100% :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I've updated the answer with the alternative solution, which uses the same method as the one that worked for battery. Don't forget to accept if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! I switched both `Device Care` items to `Silent and minimized`, and will wait for 4 days to see if it reappears (it does not appear very often in the first place). I won't forget to give you the bounty if it works ^_^

Comment: As an update to this information, I found that `General notifications` / `General Messages` handles the low battery and charging notifications. I recommend only making these silent, as minimizing them will disable any sort of warning before the device dies.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can't post comments yet, so here's my thoughts in an answer.

Try searching for the package name of the app that's showing the notifications. [A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&ei=kQgTXr7TB4mCyAObmJPADg&q=these%20notifications%20can%27t%20be%20turned%20off%20root&oq=these%20notifications%20can%27t%20be%20turned%20off%20root&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15243.15585..15760...0.3..0.101.331.3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i160.lZuNsztMJLk&ved=0ahUKEwj-3-Hr3u7mAhUJAXIKHRvMBOgQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) finds [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff&hl=en_US) app which seems to do what you're looking for.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Rebuilding a system app without activities is a **terrible** idea. Not to be so blunt, but the core firmware is not built in a one function per activity fashion.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't do that with a system app. But if it wasn't a system app (I thought OP used a custom battery monitor app), it might be possible.

Comment: A regular app should not have activities removed to disable notifications, since you would have an option in the app or the standard notifications options for that. That explanation doesn't really make it any better of an idea.

Comment: Huh ok. I thought a standard app could set it's notifications to be unswipable as well, just like a system app can. Anyway, thanks for the insight.

Comment: An app can set persistent or recurring notifications, but the system notification settings override that.