# Rooting android device without internet connection

Tags: root-access

I need to root my Samsung s10 with android 10, but **without internet connection to the device**. I can download all necessary files to my PC and connect the device to the PC (use ADB \ Odin), but the device itself doesn't have an internet connection.

I know the best tool to root android is Magisk, but from what I understood it must have internet connectionn. Does anyone know how can I do that? maybe use Magisk in some other way?...

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to root Samsung Galaxy S10/S10e/S10+](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212265/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s10-s10e-s10)

Comment: rooting involves several steps, but no step requires internet connection. instead it requires a lot of research, reading, understanding, reading again. especially S10 has some pitfalls you will end up bricked. read careful [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3918699), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535), [3](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3919714), [4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4020123)

Comment: @alecxs Rooting with Magisk indeed requires internet connection. There was an issue report about this: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/3172 . “No Install button” was fixed, but the ability to root without an internet connection was not restored by that fix. I confirm it on my device.

Comment: @alecxs I disabled "Check Updates" in the settings of Magisk Manager. Nothing changed. Or which auto-update are you talking about?

Comment: @alecxs Setting the update channel to the empty URL and disabling checking updates changes nothing. I can't locate that JSON file. Is it in `/Android/data` in the internal memory?

Comment: @beroal just tried with 8.0.7 does not work. you are left with 4.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an internet access to root a devices as far as i know... This might help.. https://www.thecustomdroid.com/samsung-galaxy-s10-twrp-magisk-root-guide/
**Don't modify any commands or steps given here.. if things aren't going as described DON'T PROCEED** I myself have bricked 2 smartphone so i'd suggest you not to root it if you don't have enough knowledge about rooting!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
However in the link you sent there is a need for internet connection - in Step 1.5, in the Magisk manager app, there is no menu and "install Magisk" options without internet connection. Do you know of a way to install Magisk without Magisk Manager feature?
It actually shows something like this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10022598/92601691-6cfceb00-f2ad-11ea-9de2-bec0caa599bd.png

Comment: @terry1990 Did it solve your issue?

Comment: No, see above edited answer

Comment: @terry1990 I searched the web but didn't get any relevant answer. Can you tell what's the issue with your phone? wifi problem?  If you have internet in your pc why don't you just do a reverse tethering and share pc's internet to your phone and you're good to go. You just have to install an app for reverse tethering. Download the apk and transfer it to your phone. Windows 10 has this feature built-in.  You can try this... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free&hl=en&gl=US